# Why is Sheldon such a big fan of Doctor Who?

Tags: character, the-big-bang-theory, doctor-who

In some episodes of *The Big Bang Theory* we can see that Sheldon is a big fan of Doctor from *Doctor Who*.

We also see that one of his greatest dreams is transferring his mind into a cybernetic body.

On the other hand, in *Doctor Who* we see that Doctor is the greatest enemy of Daleks and Cybermen - living creatures in cybernetic bodies.

Why is Sheldon such a big fan of Doctor, who is fighting with something that is Sheldon's greatest dream?

Comment: This is a pretty odd question. You may as well ask why a police officer, whose job it is to keep the public safe, would be a fan of slasher horror films where lots of people get murdered.

Comment: The difference between Sheldon and the officer is, that if the movies come to real life, the officer wouldn't take a machete to slaughter people, while Sheldon meeting Cybermen, to their "You have to be converted!" wolud answer "At last! What took you so long?"

Answer (score 3):

You're misreading why the Cybermen are considered a villain.

It has nothing to do with the cybernetic upgrades. It has everything to do with them **forcing cybernetic upgrades on every living creature**.

The Doctor always avoids killing except in cases where he must kill the aggressor in order to defend the victim. Similarly, he does not kill Cybermen unless there is no other way to save the Cybermen's victims.

Sheldon *wishes* to become cybernetic, which means that it doesn't actually conflict with the Doctor's view on the Cybermen (or other cybernetic beings). Only if Sheldon were to e.g. force his friends to become cybernetic would a conflict arise.

Comment: From what I recall of the Cybermen in the post-reboot Doctor Who, there's not much left of the original person's mind after they've been "upgraded"/converted into Cybermen. For somebody like Sheldon, who considers himself to be intellectually superior to almost everybody, I doubt becoming part of what's essentially a hivemind would be appealing.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Sheldon never stated he wishes to become a Cyberman. Sheldon's dream is _"transferring **his mind** into a cybernetic body"_.

Comment: Yes, I know. The question, however, is premised on the idea that the two are the same thing. Addressing the fact that they're not - a Cyberman is not just a single consciousness inside a cybernetic body - would improve your answer, and further illustrate that there's no contradiction between Sheldon's desire and his liking Doctor Who.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: As I read it, the question is premised on the idea that the Doctor opposes the Cybermen _because they are cybernetic_ ("we see that Doctor is the greatest enemy of Daleks and Cybermen - living creatures in cybernetic bodies"), which I specifically address and counter in my answer. What resolves the apparent conflict is _Sheldon's consent_ (he's not being forced into it) rather than whether or not he becomes part of a hivemind or not.